# Restricting object values with Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is there any way to type an object in Flow such that it can have any number of keys but they values of those keys can be typed.

i.e. a type that would enforce that all the values in an object are strings

```
const validObject = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz'
}

const invalidObject = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 'baz'
}
```

The invalid object would fail because it has a number as one of the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know the exact shape of your object, but you know it maps from `string -> string` then you can use a dictionary type:

```
type Valid = {[key:string]: string}

const validObject: Valid = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz'
}

const invalidObject: Valid = {
  foo: 1, // error
  bar: 'baz'
}
```

---

If you know the shape of your object, you can define a type like this

```
type Valid = {
  foo: string,
  bar: string
}

const validObject: Valid = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz'
}

const invalidObject: Valid = {
  foo: 1, // error
  bar: 'baz'
}
```

Moreover, you can use something called "hamburger syntax" using `{| |}` to make the type an `exact` type that only allows `foo` and `bar` to be valid. ([Read more here](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types))

```
// @flow

type Valid = {|
  foo: string,
  bar: string
|}

const validObject: Valid = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz',
  baz: 'foo' // error
}
```